# Clear my database after a unexpected error in tests with phpunit

Tags: php, api, testing, phpunit, integration-testing

I'm testing a API, in the setup i make a factory to create and save a user, after i request with curl.

after that a clear the user in tearDown like the example below:

```
private User user;
/**
* @before
*/
public function setup() {
   //open connection here
   $this->user = UserFactory::makeUser();
   $this->user->save();
   $this->sendRequestToLoginWihtThatUser($this->user);
}
//execute test
/**
* @after
*/
public function tearDown() {
   $this->user->remove();
  //close connection here
}
```

Even though in the middle of the request I a get a error that break the test or in the tests too. I don't want to code stop, I want to execute tearDown to remove the user from my database. Any suggestions?
I'm new to testing, so any ideias will help. Thx guys.

Comment: Errors are meant to interrupt the code execution, as they literally mean "the program doesn't know what to do with this". There is no way around that, you can't force it to keep executing. There is a bit of a dirty solution where you could check if the user exists at the beginning of `setUp` and then create one if it doesn't.

Comment: Wrong approach. You actually do not want to use a database at all while testing. Test setups generally should be stateless.

Comment: @El_Vanja In this case I always create a user, but i want to always clear he after the tests. When a error happens and the code is interrupt that user remains in the testDatabase.

Comment: @arkascha I can't figure out another way to test without the database, you have any suggestion to this scenario: Sending a request, pass validations and return a response? I'm making the assertion on the json response. I work with test for one week now, I'm a bit lost in this new enviroment, and I have to implement it from 0. Sorry for any english mistake.

Comment: You cannot make the application execute the clean up if it fails before it reaches that step. Tell me, are you using a separate testing database? @arkascha That is true only of unit tests. What the OP has at hand is either a functional or an integration test, where db interaction is not only allowed, but necessary.

Comment: I fail to see why you need a database for that. But anyway. If this "only" is about reacting to the error that occurs during the request you want to test, then you should install an error handler, just as you do for your production code. Only that the handler in your test suite does what you want to happen: the teardown.

Comment: @El_Vanja I'm using the same database to test and develop, the project don't have any production release yet.

Comment: @arkascha I will ask my superior how we can implement the error handler, thank you for the sugestion. He demands the tests that way, like they are passing trough all the API request process until the final response.

Comment: I found it a good practice to keep a separate database for testing (in the development environment). Same name as your actual db, but with a "test" prefix or suffix. You copy the table structure (not the data) and in your test environment config you specify that test db. That way, if anything fails, you know you can safely truncate the entire database to avoid any leftover data. It has the drawback of having to keep the structure up to date with the actual db, but that can be automated as well (execute any migrations on both dbs).

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja we don't do this yet, i will suggest it to my superior, I think it will help us a lot.